# @ObservedObject does not get updated

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to update a view with a simple Observable pattern, but it doesn't happen for some reason. The Publisher gets updated, but the subscriber doesn't. I've simplified to the code below. When you click the Add button, the view doesn't get updated and also the variable.

I'm using this function (NetworkManager.shared.saveNew()), because I update after a CloudKit notification. If you know a workaround, I'd be pleased to know!

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

public class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = NetworkManager()

    @Published var list = [DataSource]()

    init() {
        self.list = [DataSource(id: "Hello", action: [1], link: "http://hello.com", year: 2020)]
    }

    func saveNew(item: DataSource) {
        self.list.append(item)

    }
}

struct DataSource: Identifiable, Codable {

    var id: String
    var action: [Int]
    var link: String
    var year: Int

    init(id: String, action: [Int], link: String, year: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.action = action
        self.link = link
        self.year = year
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var list = NetworkManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add") {
                NetworkManager.shared.saveNew(item: DataSource(id: "GoodBye", action: [1], link: "http://goodbye", year: 2030))

            }
            List(list.list, id:\.id) { item in
                Text(item.id)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be used same instance of `NetworkManager`, so here is fixed variant (and better to name manager as `manager` but not as `list`)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var manager = NetworkManager.shared // << fix !!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add") {
                self.manager.saveNew(item: DataSource(id: "GoodBye", action: [1], link: "http://goodbye", year: 2030))

            }
            List(manager.list, id:\.id) { item in
                Text(item.id)
            }
        }

    }
}
```